# Send redirect URL in the text body of mail using nodemailer

Tags: node.js

I am tring to send mail which is working but i want to send redirect url into the mail text

```
var mailOptions = {
          from: 'sachincoder96@gmail.com',
          to: user_info.email,
          subject: 'Sign up confirmation.',
          text: 'Go to this link for confirmation of your registration'+ http://localhost:8000/user/registration/confirmation?id=id
        };
```

but due to ':' and // this the i am getting error.

```
 text: 'Go to this link for confirmation of your registration'+ localhost:8000/user/registration/confirmation?id=id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is part of the string, your syntax is invalid.

```
text: 'Go to this link for confirmation of your registration http://localhost:8000/user/registration/confirmation?id=id'
```